# How do I convert character varying to timestamp in postgresql which is in the format [ "2020-09-21T13:56:58Z" ]

Tags: sql, date, datetime, formatting, postgresql-9.2

I tried doing this but got an error as:

> ERROR: column "2020-09-21t13:56:58z" does not exits

```
Select to_timestamp("2020-09-21T13:56:58Z", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ");
```

Comment: did you specify a table to select from?

Comment: My column name is "date"

Comment: yes but you have to specify a table like `SELECT to_timestamp(/*date*/) FROM table_1 ;`

Comment: select to_timestamp(date, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ") from raw_events;

Comment: and i got error as : ERROR: column "yyyy-mm-ddthh24:mi:ssz" does not exist in raw_events

Comment: Your code works fine if you use the correct string delimiters:  `Select to_timestamp('2020-09-21T13:56:58Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SSZ')`.  I'm voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Strings need to be enclose in single quotes in SQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try `to_char()` instead. As follows -

Sample data

```
create table a (
  date_time timestamp
  );
  
insert into a (date_time) values ('2020-09-21T13:56:58Z')
```

`SELECT`

```
select to_char(date_time, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHHH24:MI:SSZ') as time
from a
```

Result:

```
time
2020-09-21ST13:56:58Z
```

[See db<>fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ab7VTaQRoSxZqCfpc3qDMr/2)

Comment: ERROR: Invalid digit, Value '-', Pos 4, Type: Decimal Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Invalid digit, Value '-', Pos 4, Type: Decimal code: 1207 context: 2020-11-01T01:04:17Z query: 541524 location: :0 process: query0_117_541524 [pid=0] -----------------------------------------------

Comment: @VardhamanJain - see test the data in the link with the answer, try the values you are working in that site

Comment: @VardhamanJain edited answer with sample data from link